# Django queryset and jQuery dynamic table calculation

Tags: javascript, jquery, django-views, datatables, django-queryset

First I can't re-do the example on this video I tried but the table doesn't appear?

[Link to the Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yfj-gpAibEo)

I just want to make a dynamic table in which I calculate the total price using Js as it present in picture.
[image]

First my views.py is:

```
def Invoic_billing(request, id_itm):
    the_invoice = Invoices.objects.get(id=id_itm)
    AllItemes   = contrat_items.objects.filter(Ctra_Nbr_id=the_invoice.Cntrat_Nbr_id)   
    context={
        'title':'Invoice',
        'the_invoice':the_invoice,
        'AllItemes':AllItemes,
    }
    return render(request,'Home/Scheduling/Invoices/Invoices_billing.html',context)
```

the model.py is :

```
class contrat_items(models.Model):
    Ctra_Nbr  = models.ForeignKey(contrat, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    Item_Ctra = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    Item_Code = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    othr_Code = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    Price     = models.DecimalField(max_digits=15, decimal_places=2,null=True)
    page      = models.PositiveIntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    post_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    author    = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

And my Html page is:

```
        <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-7">
        <h3>Contract Items Details</h3>
            <div class="card card-body">
            <table id="table_id" class="table-wrapper table-sm">
            <thead class="thead-light"><tr>
                <th>Page N°</th>
                <th>Item Description</th>
                <th>Code 1</th>
                <th>Code 2</th>
                <th>Quantity</th>
                <th></th>
            </tr></thead>
            <tbody>
            <tr >
            {% for Field in AllItemes %}
                <td>P.{{Field.page}}</td>
                <td>{{Field.Item_Ctra}}</td>
                <td>{{Field.Item_Code}}</td>
                <td>{{Field.othr_Code}}</td>
                <td> <input class="form-control mr-1" placeholder="1" name="select_date" type="number" min="0"  pattern="\d*"/></td>
                <td><input type="button" value='Add' item={{Field.Item_Ctra}} onclick="addItem({'Quantity':this.select_date,'item':this.Item_Ctra,'price':this.Price})"></td>          
            </tr>
            {% endfor %}
            </tbody>        
            </table>
            </div>
        </div>
        
        <div class="col-md-5">
        <h3>Billing Details</h3>
            <div class="card card-body">
            <table id="table_id2" class="table-wrapper table-sm">
            <thead class="thead-light"><tr>
                <th>Item Description</th>
                <th>Price.U</th>
                <th>Total</th>
            </tr></thead>
            <tbody>
            <tr >
            {% for Field in AllItemes %}
                <td>{{Field.Item_Ctra}}</td>
                <td>{{Field.Price}}</td>  
                <td>{{Field.Price}}</td>      
            </tr>
            {% endfor %}
            </tbody>        
            </table>
            </div>
         <div class="card card-body">
        <div class="row"><div class="col-md-6"> Total invoice</div>
                        <div class="col-md-6"> Sum</div></div>
         <hr>
         <div class="row"><div class="col-md-6"></div>
                        <div class="col-md-6"> {{the_invoice.Total_amount}}</div></div>
          
         </div></div></div></div><br></div>
    {% block js %}
    
    
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/dt/jszip-2.5.0/dt-1.10.18/af-2.3.0/b-1.5.2/b-colvis-1.5.2/b-flash-1.5.2/b-html5-1.5.2/b-print-1.5.2/cr-1.5.0/fh-3.1.4/r-2.2.2/datatables.min.css"/>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.36/pdfmake.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.36/vfs_fonts.js"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'Home/js/datatables.min.js' %}"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready( function () {
        $('#table_id').DataTable({});
        $('#table_id2').DataTable({});
    
        });
</script>

<script>  
</script>
{% endblock %}
```

I am really new in Js and want to make a script with js to calculate price by Quantity and the total amount.

Comment: Hi, please show your attempts .

Comment: I am trying to do it by the hard way (in backend) see my other related issue
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68293407/get-values-from-input-and-excute-function-django/68293863#68293863