# get values from input and excute function django

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, django-views, django-templates

I have two inputs in my HTML page and I want to send them to a function in Django views.py.

so I have a table as shown :[image]

And I want to take the Quantity and disc values from the inputs + another value from the from
and the HTML code is:

```
<table id="table_id" class="table-wrapper table-sm">
    <thead class="thead-light"><tr>
        <th>Item Description</th>
        <th>Quantity</th>
        <th>Disc %</th>
        <th></th>
    </tr></thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr >
    {% for Field in AllItemes %}

        <td>{{Field.Item_Code}}</td>
        <td> <input class="form-control mr-1" placeholder="1" name="select_date" type="number" min="0"  pattern="\d*"/></td>
        <td> <input class="form-control mr-1" placeholder="0" name="select_Disc" type="number" min="0"  pattern="\d*"/></td>
        
        <td><a href="{% url 'Up_InvoiceTACH' Field.Item_Code select_date select_Disc %}" class="btn btn-info btn-sm">Add</a></td>
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
    </tbody>        
    </table>
```

my views.py is:

```
def Up_InvoiceTACH(request, id_itm, id_itm2 , id_itm3):
   pass
```

and the URL is like this:

```
 path('up_InvoceTACH/<int:id_itm>/<int:id_itm2>/<int:id_itm3>/', views.Up_InvoiceTACH, name='up_InvoceTACH'),
```

So how do I send those three parameters especially from the inputs?

Answer (score 0):

A better approach would be using Django forms.
**Example**

index.html

```html
<form action="/your-name/" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form }}
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms

class NameForm(forms.Form):
    your_name = forms.CharField(label='Your name', max_length=100)
```

views.py

```
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.shortcuts import render

from .forms import NameForm

def get_name(request):
    # if this is a POST request we need to process the form data
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # create a form instance and populate it with data from the request:
        form = NameForm(request.POST)
        # check whether it's valid:
        if form.is_valid():
            # process the data in form.cleaned_data as required
            # ...
            # redirect to a new URL:
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/thanks/')

    # if a GET (or any other method) we'll create a blank form
    else:
        form = NameForm()

    return render(request, 'name.html', {'form': form})
```

Comment: Many thanks, but this way still lack one field (3 parameters)
2 from input and 3rd is row ID. however, I faced another issue that I can't receive the data in my view.py (many rows and forms) it works only when we have one form.

Comment: If you created X forms then you need to write the same code X times  and you can return them in the render as {'form1': form1, 'form2': form2 } and so fourth.

Comment: this is just an example, you need to specify the fields you need in your form.